# Paracord Question

Tags: discussion

I took the tour, read through the post of on-topic items and saw that there is a tag for paracord and for knot tying.

Before I post, I wanted to make sure this was on topic as to not clog up the flagging/vtc queue.

I bought a spool of paracord that has begun to unravel and tangle up, I'm looking for advice on how to go about untangling it before it gets completely out of hand.

Is this on-topic?

Comment: I think you will get better answers on Lifehacks Stack Exchange but I can not rule out it being accepted here.

Comment: I checked LifeHacks and didn't find any tags that would seem appropriate for my question. I will ask here as there is paracord tag and if it doesn't fit here hopefully it can be migrated. @Willeke

Comment: I am likely to post an answer on which ever site you use. But the tag paracord here is more about using paracord. On Lifehacks I would use a tag like string if they have it.

Comment: Just because there are no tags for this on Lifehacks doesn't mean it would be off-topic there.